# Cycles viewport is dark compared to EEVEE

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, light, eevee-render-engine

When I look at my scene in the EEVEE viewport everything appears fine. But when I turn to cycles, everything turns grey (total silhouette, no light whatsoever) unless I am looking through the 3D camera.

Why is this?

[image: Dark Scene whilw in Cycles]

[image: normal scene in Eevee]

Comment: Problems like these are usually related to the GPU. What is your GPU, and have you done a recent update?

Comment: As you can probably tell I'm a brginner... I'm using my potato-PC's CPU and haven't made any changs